# How can I create a block that shows the total items in my cart?

Tags: ajax, ubercart

I'm using [Ubercart ajax cart](http://drupal.org/project/uc_ajax_cart), and I want to create a static block with AJAX that only shows the total items in the cart.

How can I go about doing this? Is there a module that has this functionality?

Comment: do you make your urbercart threw views or using any module?

Answer (score 3):

You can test this one -

Put below code in your page (create new page content) and select input format "php" and hit preview button you will get what you want (if cart is not empty).

```
<?php
        $items = uc_cart_get_contents();

        foreach($items as $item){
            while(list($key,$value) = each($item)){     
                if($key == 'qty')$qty = $value;
                if($key == 'price')$price = $value;
            }       
            $total_qty += $qty;
            $total_price += $qty*$price;
       }
       echo 'Total Quantity : '.$total_qty.' Total Price : '.uc_currency_format($total_price);
    ?>
```

Comment: How can I add taxes on $total_price  price?